# CMake link atlas and llapack

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

How do I tell the compiler, in CMake where a specific library is?

For example, using terminal the following works:

```
g++ main.cpp hmm.cpp -I /usr/include/atlas -L /usr/lib64/atlas/ -llapack -lblas
```

But, how do I include the following inside of my CMake file?

I am using the ROS operating system and currently have:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(build src/hmm.cpp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way of finding libraries is to use [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_package). It is often necessary to provide a FindLIBNAME. For LAPACK, CMake [already ships with one](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindLAPACK). For atlas you will have to provide one yourself.

You use them like this:

```
find_package(LAPACK)
if(LAPACK_FOUND)
  target_compile_options(my_exe_target ${LAPACK_LINKER_FLAGS})
  target_link_library(my_exe_target ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  # panick
endif()
```

Usually find_package would also export the include directory, but this doesn't seem to be the case for `FindLAPACK`, which is really strange. You might want to provide a version that doesn't suck, [like this one](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindLAPACK.cmake).

Comment: @user1326876 Then don't upvote it and be more precise about what didn't work.

Comment: I upvoted it to show my appreciation in your answer. It did work in the end though, so thank you for this.

Comment: @user1326876 Good to know. Up-votes on StackOverflow should really mean that the content of the answer or question is good.